# java  mvc prevent access to views

Tags: java, spring

If I have several views in my project, how do I prevent someone from accessing a page using the jsp file, when the @RequestMapping should be used?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JSP files should reside under the /WEB-INF directory, where the container itself disallows access.